# Java - enact an event (updating GUI JLabel representing changing Calendar object) every second?

Tags: java, user-interface, calendar

I have a custom-made Calendar object in a Java file.  Rather than explaining what it is (it's rather complicated), I'll just say that it is NOT the current system date/time, but does vary depending on the current system date/time, and as such, changes every second.  I would like to get a constant up-to-the-second representation of it in a GUI.  I have no idea how to do this though.  So far I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class movingClock extends JFrame
{
    Container c;
    JLabel year, month, date, hour, minute, second;

    public movingClock(Calendar cal)
    {
        super("Custom Clock");

        c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        year = new JLabel("year: " +cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        c.add(year);

        month = new JLabel("month: " +cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        c.add(month);

        date = new JLabel("date: " +cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        c.add(date);

        hour = new JLabel("hour: " +cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        c.add(hour);

        minute = new JLabel("minute: " +cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        c.add(minute);

        second = new JLabel("second: " +cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        c.add(second);

        setSize(600,200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); //avoids DST

        Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance(UTC);  //this is the current system time in UTC (this way, we avoid Daylight Savings Time)
        Calendar custom = my custom Calendar object;

        movingClock clock = new movingClock(custom);
    }
}
```

To avoid posting a much longer, more complicated program, I used pseudocode (if you can even call it that) for my custom Calendar object (which is created in the 5th-to-last line of the code).  I need to update each of my JLabels once per second, and since my custom object is dependent on the actual system date/time and therefore changes every second, **I believe I will need to re-create it once per second** (by carrying out that line of code once per second), and probably call my constructor once per second.  I'm not familiar with any classes/methods that can allow me to do what I'm trying to do.  Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks!

P.S. I know my GUI is not pretty or neat as it is, but I tried to keep it as simple as possible for this post.

Comment: [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: [Some good examples at use of Swing Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a992484%20%22swing%20timer%22).

Comment: While the posted duplicate does represent the current system time, the basic priniciple of updating a `JLabel` every second is what is been demonstrated (and from my humble interruption) and what was asked for.  Since we don't have the formula you are intending to use to modify the date/time value with, it would be, otherwise, impossible to provide a more accurate answer

Comment: Thanks for providing the link.  I'm having trouble making sense of most of that file.  I've never learned @override or try/catch.  Is the Timer part (along with the method that updates the clock) basically all I need to adapt into my existing program, or is the other content of the constructor important for what I'm trying to do too?